# Layout, absolute position issues in ie6

Tags: css, scroll, chat, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to produce something similar to an instant messaging type interface.

the page has the following requirements:

- page is fixed (it doesn't scroll)
- fixed banner at top
- a scrollable panel in the center containing chat messages
- a fixed div at the bottom containing a textarea for input

Here's the markup:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="banner"></div>

    <div id="content">
    <div id="messageAndControlContainer">

        <div id="messageContainer">
            <div id="message">
                <p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p>
                <p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p>
                <p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p>
                <p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p>
                <p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p><p>chat message</p>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="control">
            <textarea>enter your message</textarea>
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

Here's the JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bzMfe/1/

This works fine in modern browsers (as in JSFiddle), but in ie6 it is totally messed up. Any ideas please?

[image: Chrome 27.0]

[image: IE 6.0]

Answer (score 0):

Solved using expressions for the panel in the middle holding the messages.

```
#message {
  height:expression(document.body.clientHeight-170);
  width:expression(document.body.clientWidth-40);
}
```